# How to show all asked-for Translation Strings in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, internationalization

When Rails functions are asking for a translation (`I18n.translate`), I don't want to analyze their code in order to get the exact scopes etc.

How can I add a debug output into the console for every string that was asked for?

**Examples:**

```
I18n.t 'errors.messages.invalid', :scope => :active_record 
# Translation for 'activerecord.errors.messages.invalid' (not) found

label(:post, :title)
# Translation for 'activerecord.attributes.post.title' not found
# Translation for 'views.labels.post.title' not found
```

Comment: Until now, I couldn't a better answer than "read the Rails code" or "Use your own translation strings" (as in the first example).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a very elegant solution, but it's worked for me. I've created an initialiser:

```
require 'i18n'

if (Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?) && ENV['DEBUG_TRANSLATION']
  module I18n
    class << self
      def translate_with_debug(*args)
        Rails.logger.debug "Translate : #{args.inspect}"
        translate_without_debug(*args)
      end
      alias_method_chain :translate, :debug
    end
  end
end
```

You can then run commands like the following:

```
$ DEBUG_TRANSLATION=true rake cucumber
```

...and you'll see all the translations being attempted dumped to STDOUT. I don't consider this production code though, so I've kept it in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/1431633), and not checked it into my main project source control at this stage.

Noddy, but it does the job.

Comment: I've updated to include changes from Andrea D'Amico (see other answer). Thanks Andrea - not sure why I didn't do that in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

Just a small change to put I18n debug messages in the log:

substitute this line:

```
puts "Translate: #{args.inspect}"
```

with

```
Rails.logger.debug "Translate : #{args.inspect}"
```

Comment: Thanks Andrea; I've included this change in the answer above. +1.